# Unable to click on a png image using selenium webdirver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a PNG image. following code finds the image, retrieves the title, but doesn't click. And doesn't throw any error.

While the page is loading, if I click somewhere on the page, then my script works. It clicks on the PNG image. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www1.macys.com/shop/bed-bath/bath-rugs-bath-mats?id=8240&edge=hybrid");
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement we = w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'http://assets.macys.com/navapp/web20/assets/img/socialshopping/poll_create.png')]")));
System.out.println(we.getAttribute("title"));
we.click();
```

Comment: Couple things I can think to try.  One is to put in driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); after the driver.get().  The other is to have Selenium click in the page somewhere, then click the create poll image.  I'm not sure why it won't click on the image directly.

Comment: It works if I click in the page somewhere and then click on the PNG image. But I couldn't understand why it doesn't click on image when I don't click anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this StackOverflow question addresses issues with clicking on an image that may or may not have an action attributed to it.  It circles around using the 'perform()' method rather than 'click()' to execute that image's action.

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337353/correct-way-to-focus-an-element-in-webdriver-using-java).

Comment: tried using Actions class also. it didn't work.                     Actions act = new Actions(driver);
  act.moveToElement(we);
  act.build();
  act.perform();
  we.click();