# How can I focus on an element using Webdriver JS?

Tags: webdriver

e.g. if I get an instance of an element using

```
var termsLink = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('wd-terms'));
```

There dont seem to be any methods available on the resulting WebElement object to set focus on the target element, in that case how can I do this using Webdriver JS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems other the java bindings for webdriver have a method `moveToElement` but looking into the source code of my webdriver instance, `"selenium-webdriver": "^2.46.1"` obtained via NPM, the `moveToElement` method doesnt seem to exist.

The best technique I found was

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('some-id')).sendKeys('');
```

per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337353/correct-way-to-focus-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)