# selenium java - can't detect element x,y location

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot, captcha

i am trying to capture the captcha image from a web page using the following code

```
WebElement captchaEl = driver.findElement(By.id("captchaLogin"));
//System.out.println("Captcha: "+ source);
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
Point point = captchaEl.getLocation();
int eleX = point.getX();
int eleY = point.getY();
int eleWidth = captchaEl.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = captchaEl.getSize().getHeight();
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(eleX, eleY, eleWidth, eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(outputFileName));
```

It ends up capturing some other portion in the page, rather than the captcha image. Although it works if phantomjs driver is used, but doesn't work if chromedriver or geckodriver(firefoxdriver) is used. What could be the problem here?

Comment: try to put some focus over the capcha

Comment: @ShubhamJain how? by clicking on it first?

Comment: Action classes .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337353/correct-way-to-focus-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: @ShubhamJain unfortunately that doesn't work either. i added new Actions(driver).moveToElement(captchaEl).click().perform();
to top it, i added Thread.sleep(1000); so that it waits for 1 more sec.

Comment: Might try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832322/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-a-specific-element-rather-than-entire-page-usin

Comment: @smit9234 i am practically using the same code already. the problem is with captchaEl.getLocation() giving a incorrect location of captchaEl.